# attach / save files against a database record

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Has anyone every attempted to save various files against database record?

e.g. pdfs, images, text files, word docs etc.

If so is there a good/simple way of going about it? I'm looking into it now and unfortunately not getting anywhere.

Thanks,

Comment: Save the file in a blob field

Comment: Yes, some apps. of mine are *attempting* that many times a day :)

Comment: Which DBMS and client libray do you use ? Is that the Sybase ASA and FireDAC ? Please include the relevant tags in all your questions. They are crucial for you to get the optimal answer.

Comment: Which version of FireDAC (it might be in the about dialog opened through the IDE menu FireDAC | About) ?

Comment: @TLama sorry for the late reply.....FireDAC 8.0.5 (Build 3365)